# Strip out unused classes

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I want to make a library jar the has all the dependencies, but stuff that're not used are stripped.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile 'com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.11.2'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.54'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.54'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    task("jar${variant.name}", type: Jar) {
        description "Bundles compiled .class files into a JAR file for $variant.name."
        dependsOn variant.javaCompile
        from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
        exclude '**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html'
        baseName = 'myLib'
    }
}

task jarTask(type: Jar) {
    baseName="myLib"
    from 'src/main/java'
}

task includeAll(type: Jar) {
    baseName = "myLib"

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }

    }

    with jarTask
}

configurations {
    jarConfiguration
}

artifacts {
    jarConfiguration jarTask
}
```

Currently, I'm using `gradle clean includeall` to create the jar. How to strip all unused stuff out?

Asking because I have to import `javax.naming.Binding` for BC, and importing more stuff seems crazy and unneeded.

What I need - stand alone jar with all dependencies, but methods/classes not used are removed.